# How to fill a large group of vertices with faces? Using F for Fill doesnt work, weird results

Tags: vertices, faces, topology

Im struggling to deform large shapes, especially with proportional editing as the overall shape of the object gets lost/deformed, or the proportional editing zone isnt big enough so the part im editing gets deformed... Using H and alt+H to hide things is an OK solution sometimes, but my main aim is to keep the surrounding topology flow intact, and hiding faces/vertices helps, but only if those vertices/faces are far away.

Anyway, I am trying another way to get the desired shape, by using a circles made up of vertices, and shaping those circles as desired, before attaching this new part to the overall shape.

But now I have 100s of vertices in these circles, but they dont have faces between them..

Is there an easy way to fill a group of vertices with straight quad faces?
I can do it manually, by selection 4 vertices and pressing F, but doing that over a 100 times manually is really wasteful... So what are your tips and tricks for solving this?

Maybe there is some macro/program that helps solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Images:

[image: Ships hull]
[image: Using Fill F]

Comment: Using Loft I get this error:

    new_faces = bridge_create_faces(object, bm, faces, self.twist)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\mesh_looptools.py", line 1485, in bridge_create_faces
    new_faces.append(bm.faces.new([bm.verts[v] for v in faces[i]]))
ValueError: faces.new(...): found the same (BMVert) used multiple times

Comment: could you please share your file? At least these edges that you're trying to fill

Comment: Alright, I will upload it to drive and edit the Q

Comment: I added the blend file

Comment: see my edit, it seems to work fine, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the *LoopTools* addon, select the edges in *Edge* selection mode and right click > *LoopTools > Loft*:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it only works in some case, as it isnt possible to close off the whole shape, but this atleast does 80%, if selection the right vertices, if i select too many vertices it will throw this error:
 "found the same (BMVert) used multiple times"

Comment: Yes it works alright, I was hoping it would connect to the ship aswell, but i can do that manually. Thanks for the answer im sure this will save me a lot of time in the future as im always filling holes haha

Comment: My bad, if you are in Edge selection mode it works with one Loft operation